# Vue JS - all components re-rendered when navigating to single item component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an ecommerce application and I am trying to re-write the frontend with vue js. I have a page that lists all the products and then a link for the users that takes them to a page where they can see details of a single product.

The users can navigate to this link via the 'router-link' handler.

However when this link is clicked, the users are taken to a 'show' template for a single product, but the rest of the products are continuing to be displayed.

Any ideas or thoughts as to what is missing from this scenario?

Thanks,

Robert

// ProductPage.vue // this shows all the products

```
    <template>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="header col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <h1>Products</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-list text-center">
                <h5>Select a Product</h5>
                <table class="product-table">
                    <tr class="products row">

                        <Product v-for="product in products" :product="product" :key="product.product_id" />

               
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </main>
</template>

<script setup>

import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { allProducts } from "../http/product-api";
import Product from "../components/products/Product.vue";

const products = ref([])




onMounted(async () => {
    const { data } = await allProducts()
    products.value = data.data
    console.log(products)
});





</script>
```

// Product.vue: this shows a single product on the products listing page

```
<template>



    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">

        <h2 class="product-title"><router-link :to="'/show/' + product.product_id">{{ product.product_name }}</router-link></h2>


        <img class="single-product-image" src="/navy-dress.webp"/>

        <p class="single-product-price">{{ product.product_price }}</p>
    </div>    

</template>



<script setup>

        defineProps({
            product: Object
        })




</script>
```

// Show.vue // takes the user to the page where it should just render one product, but at the moment all products are being rendered

```
    <template>
    <div class="container">
        <router-link to="/index">&lt; Back</router-link>

        <h1 class="product-title">{{ product.product_name }}</h1>

        <h2>params id: {{ id }}</h2>

        <img class="single-product-image" src="/navy-dress.webp"/>

        <p class="single-product-price">{{ product.product_price }}</p>
    </div>
    
</template>


<script setup>

import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { showProduct } from "../../http/product-api";
import Product from "../../components/products/Product.vue";
import axios from 'axios';


const product = ref([])

const route = useRoute()


onMounted(async () => {
    const uri = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/products/" + route.params.id;
    axios.get(uri).then(response => {
        product.value = response.data;
    });
    console.log(product);
});





</script>
```

// router (index.js)

```
    import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
    import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
    import ShowView from '../components/products/Show.vue'
    import Index from '../pages/ProductsPage.vue'

    const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/show/:id',
      name: 'show',
      props: true,
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: ShowView
    },
    {
      path: '/index',
      name: 'index',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: Index
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: what is the target component on your router ?

Comment: The target component is 'Show'. I have updated the code above to show the router.

Comment: ProductPage.vue doesn't have it's own route in your `routes` array.  This implies that ProductPage exists above or below wherever the `<router-view>` component is being rendered.  That's why it doesn't unmount.  `<router-view>` is the only component replaced by a change in route.  Any components existing outside of router-view will remain. This is usually meant for components like headers/footers and nav menus.  If you want Show.vue to replace ProductPage.vue they should each have their own route so that VueRouter can switch between them.

Comment: Hi @yoduh thanks for your comment, maybe, but I did include a route called 'index' (see above), it is my last route, and this renders a component called Index which is the name for the 'ProductsPage.vue' import.

(See index.js top of file, "import Index from '../pages/ProductsPage.vue'").

So the component does have its own route.

Any other thoughts here?

Thanks

Comment: I could probably help solve it given a runnable example, e.g. a codesandbox, stackblitz, or github repo.

Comment: Hi @Yodah, please see runnable example hosted on my github:
https://github.com/rsy644/products-backend
https://github.com/rsy644/products-frontend.

Follow the installation instructions available in the repos. If all works, when you navigate to the home page, e.g. http://127.0.0.1:5173/, you should get an ecommerce storefront with 11 items and their titles in a tiled formation (listing page). Clicking on any of the titles directs users to a 'show' page. I wanted this page (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:5173/show/2) to just show the details of one product, but instead, all 11 are listed again.